# Representing renderable light in game world

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a 3D model of a **lantern** and placed it into Unity, and I want a light source to emit from the lantern, so I have created a *new object* in Unity called *Bulb*, and have placed a *Light* component onto it like so:

[image]
[image]

However when I see this light in my game world, it points **straight to the ground**, like this:

[image]

However I need the light to be some what like a **floating bulb**, that way I can simply move the Bulb object into the lantern before parenting them.

How exactly do I go about doing this?

Comment: Hmm...what do you mean by "floating bulb"? Do you mean you want to have an actual in-game model for the bulb, rather than it just being a point light (which has no physical appearance)?

Comment: I literally want to have a light source that has a physical appearance (I should have been more clear on that), that way when the light is placed inside the lantern, it looks as if the lantern is lit, rather than the light pointing towards the ground.

Comment: You could try representing the light bulb with a lightly-coloured transparent sphere/spheroid. Set it to not receive or cast any shadows, and have the actual light positioned inside of it to give the impression that the bulb object is the emitting light.

Comment: You're a savior, works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer if you'd like to accept it, so we can mark this question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 3D computer graphics, lights don't have a physical representation. As such, you'll need to add your own mesh to represent the lightbulb if you want it visible.

My suggestion is to use a lightly-coloured transparent sphere or spheroid mesh. (If you want to apply a glassy material to it, try looking at the suggestions offered [in this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98557/glass-material-for-unity-5) for shader ideas.) Remember to also set it to not receive or cast any shadows:

[image]

Then, position the point light inside of the lightbulb mesh to give the impression that it is emitting the light.